# Where to put code to tell Google to forget a page

Tags: html

Having trawled the internet, I see that I need the 410 code to tell Google that a page is gone forever, but nowhere can I find where or how to use it. Does it go in a folder labelled 410 with a list of URLs to be forgotten, or in the header of these pages or somewhere else and what if any associated code does it need? I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: maybe use a redirect for all pages you "deleted". like Redirect 410 /foo/bar/demo.php. see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-return-a-http-410-error-resource-permanently-does-not-exist-configuration/

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [cyberciti.biz](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-return-a-http-410-error-resource-permanently-does-not-exist-configuration/)

I removed [www.example.com/foo/file.html](http://www.example.com/foo/file.html) from my domain. But, it is still being crawled by Google/Yahoo and many other bots. How do I return a HTTP-410 gone error i.e. tell these bots that resource permanently does not exist using Apache HTTPD server on a CentOS/RHEL/Fedora/Ubuntu/Debian and Unix-like operating system?

**Answer:**

The simplest configuration is to add the following line in .htaccess file using mod_alias Redirect directive. Cd to your DocumentRoot such as /var/www/html/:

```
$ cd /var/www/html/
$ vi .htaccess
```

Append the following line:

```
Redirect gone /foo/file.html
```

OR

```
Redirect 410 /foo/bar/demo.php
```

You can also use of regular expressions using RedirectMatch directive as follows:

```
RedirectMatch gone regex-here
 
# Match all .png files in /foo/
RedirectMatch gone "/foo/\.png$"
 
# Another example for gif files starting with bar name
RedirectMatch gone "/foo/bar*\.png$"
 
# One more example. We now have resposive site so remove all old mobile friendly html pages
RedirectMatch gone "/mobilesite/*.html$"
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 options to solve this problem.

1. If you want Google Crawler to ignore a particular page for indexing just add a Meta Tag in you page header

[image: ""]

To prevent only Google web crawlers from indexing a page

2. To prevent indexing a folder you can use the robots.txt. This file should be in your root directory with the following codes:

   User-agent: *

   Disallow: /secret/

"secret" -> your foulder name

Thanks, and please let me know if the problem exists after using this.